# Emberjs: Trigger an Emberjs event on HTML5 Audio "ended" event

Tags: ember.js

Currently, we have an audio element playing in our Ember.js app.

**Ember Version:**

```
//RC3, Ember Data revision 12.
```

We're trying to get the next song to load when the current song ends.

Currently, the next song loads when we click the "next" button. 
Here's how that is set up.

**The Route:**

```
http://localhost:3000/#/player
```

**The Router Mapping:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('songs', function() {
    this.resource('song', { path: ":song_id" });
  });
  // the player's route
  this.route('player');
  // Route that redirects back to player so player can load the new song.  
  this.route('loading-next-song'); 
});
```

**The custom event**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  customEvents: {
    'ended': "ended"
  }
});
```

**The Views:**

```
// surrounds "next" button, works.
App.NextSongView = Ember.View.extend({ 
  click: function() {
    this.get('controller').send('setNextSong');
  }
});

// surrounds the player, only the click works.
App.NextSongOnEndedView = Ember.View.extend({ 
  ended: function() {
    console.log("song ended"); // doesn't fire.
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log("tests that other events work"); // fires. 
  }
})
```

**The PlayerRoute handler** 
Has the setNextSong event

```
App.PlayerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //Gets SongsController
    var songsController = this.controllerFor("songs"); 
    // Gets Current Song
    return App.Song.find(songsController.get("currentSong"));
  },
  events: {
    setNextSong: function() { 
      // Fires the "setNextSong" method on the Songs Controller
      this.controllerFor('songs').send('setNextSong'); 
      // redirects to "loading-next-song" route which
      // redirects immediately back to player. (so it can reload)
      this.transitionTo('loading-next-song'); 
    }
  }
});
```

**The Songs Controller:**
Has the setNextSong method.

```
App.SongsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  currentSong: 1,
  index: 0,
  setNextSong: function() { // loads the next song.
    var newIndex = (this.get("index") + 1);
    this.set("currentSong", this.objectAt(newIndex).get("id"));
    this.set("index", newIndex);
  }
});
```

So the click events fire, so we can trigger the next song loading. 
However we would like the next song to load automatically when the current song ends, without having to click the next button.

In the console, after the player loads, this works:

```
$('audio').on('ended', function() {
  $('button').trigger('click'); //sends 'setNextSong' to the proper controller
});
```

Is it possible to have an HTML5 audio "ended" event trigger an Ember.js event?
Or is there a better way to automatically play the next song within Ember?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you see my edit's?

Comment: I did, Thanks so much. I updated the questions with code for controllers and routes, and better labeling. Let me know if anything else needs clarification.

Comment: ok, I just updated the fiddle again to represent more your case, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/17/ the trick is in the view

Comment: the answer is also updated, let me know it the last example works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Just to show the method used in the fiddle:

```
App.NextSongOnEndedView = Ember.View.extend({
  // hook in here and subscribe to the ended event
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    var player = this.$('audio')[0];
    player.addEventListener('ended', function(event) {
      console.log("ended song");
      self.get('controller').send('setNextSong');
    });
  },
  //remove listener when removed from DOM to avoid memory leaks
  willDestroyElement: function(){
    var player = this.$('audio')[0];
    player.removeEventListener('ended');
  }
});
```

I've added also a working fiddle just to show the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/18/

In Ember.js you can define customEvents see here (http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events), example for creating a custom event in Ember.js:

**Application level**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  customEvents: {
    // player event
    'ended': "myCustomEvent"
  }
});
```

`myCutomEvent` is a method you still have to create.

**Application Route level** hook only in the ApplicationRoute if you don't have more specific Routes for your application.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    // Note: if nothing stops the event from bubbling it will end up here.
    myCustomEvent: function() {
      this.controllerFor('songs').send('setNextSong');
    }
  }
});
```

**Specific Route level**
but if you have for example an `NextSongRoute` defined then the hook should be placed more conveniently there, e.g.:

```
App.NextSongRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    myCustomEvent: function() {
      this.controllerFor('songs').send('setNextSong');
    }
  }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried a custom event, but couldn't get ended to trigger the  the method. I updated the question above to reflect the troubleshooting, in case you have any other ideas.

Comment: Can you post your controller code? The event should be handled on the controller

Comment: it would also be useful to see how your routes are defined?

Comment: Updated with controllers and routes and better labeling. Let me know if you need anything else. And thanks again for the help.

Comment: That Made is Crystal Clear. You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.